# What is the trail of logic in the sentence

Tags: objects, infinitive-constructions

Consider the sentence

> You don't need to patronize me.

To patronize is an infinitive. But I can't understand why use of *me* is right. Is it the object of the infinitive or of the need verb?  Can an infinitive phrase have its own object?

Comment: "To patronize is an infinitive." -- says who?

Comment: What is it then.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please visit the sister site [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: I now know nothing.

Comment: You will find helpful and interesting posts there. This is for advanced questions about the English language and its usage.

Comment: Yes, an infinitive verb can take an object.

Comment: Infinitives take objects just as finite verbs do. "I give money to the needy." "It's good to give money to the needy." "To give money, one needs to have money." "I visit John often." "I'd like to visit John often."

Comment: Remove the use of *need* and you'll see that *me* is still correct: *You don't patronize me.* So, the presence of *need* is a red herring in terms of your question. (At least in terms of questioning if *me* is the object of *patronize*.)

Comment: But it is a legit question syntactically.no?